# Phonegap Cordova Ajax requests 404 (Not Found) Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, http-status-code-404

My cordova version is **5.0.0**

I am getting a 404 error for the all ajax request made when the app is deployed on the device. On the web browser, it works fine but same app when deployed on a device does not work.

I tried adding following to solve the issue but it hasn't helped.

**Config.xml**

```
<access origin="*" />
```

**AndriodManiest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

I also added following in my index.html file but it didn't make any difference either.

```
<script>
    $.support.cors=true;
</script>
```

Anyone here has another trick to solve this issue?, Seems to be a quite common issue with phonegap but the fixes above worked in older vesion of the phonegap/cordova but non of them has worked in my case.

Any help would be great.

Comment: can you please give the url ?

Comment: Sorry I can't post the exact URL but I have verified the URL and it is a valid URL. It is in this format - http://www.myserver.co.uk/appname/index.php/api/getplanners

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to install the cordova-plugin-whitelist

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Credit goes to this stackoverflow article - [Ajax Command to request URL no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757593/ajax-command-to-request-url-no-longer-working)

Comment: Many thanks. I can confirm that adding this plugin made ajax work. Other people coming here for solution make sure you update you config.xml and add this: <allow-navigation href="http://yourdomain.co.uk/*" />

Comment: I had to use `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git` to install it.

Comment: One thing: No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Comment: I can't believe believe the current version of Cordova _requires_ this plugin in order for ajax requests to work. Disappointing.

Comment: @steve I don't think its disappointing but it should be better documented.

Comment: @MonkeyKing you think that cordova ajax requests should _not_ work out of the box? You are totally entitled to your opinions. I (personally) prefer libraries I use to work properly out of the box.

Comment: i'm using cordova v5.3.3, my app was working properly on Android 2.3.3 device without any issue. But when I tried on lollipop device, ajax calls were failing with "404" error. Finally installing the plugin saved my day! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was also on cordova 5.3.3 and when installing the plugin cordova says  `This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.`. but the plugin solved the problem on android 6.0.1 where POST kept returning 404.

Comment: I have installed the plugin and also created the proper config in `config.xml` and added some Content Policy Rules. I still get a 404. The request never reaches my backend so it must be blocked by the app.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I manage it fixed the issue everything I throw at the ajax always returns 404 even google :D

Answer (score 23):

It should actually add the cordova whitelist plugin :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

or in your config.xml file :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
```

but if you are using the online phonegap build service the syntax is different. You have to add the following line in your config.xml file :

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

and authorize cross domain requests :

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This is not recommended because a wildcard is used everywhere and everything is permitted. But it is perfect for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The only difference is in my config.xml I had to put it in an  node for it to take effect.

My example below:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: this is using a plugin? or vainilla cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap User. Adding this line into the config.xml is the solution for me:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a bit different. I compiled the app using a CI pipeline. So, you still need to do all the above (install the whitelist and add internet permission)

and you also need to find a Visual Studio version that will build the app correctly. Mine doesn't give an error when building, but the resulting app can't make any ajax request

After I downgraded to VS2017, it works