# Phonegap Build .ajax request returning 404

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm working on a Phonegap app which is built using the Adobe Phonegap Build service.

It currently uses Phonegap 3.7.0.

All requests made via jQuery .ajax method are returning a 404. When I submit the same request via a web browser it completes successfully.

I've seen the post ([Phonegap Cordova Ajax requests 404 (Not Found) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048453/phonegap-cordova-ajax-requests-404-not-found-error?lq=1)) about Cordova 5 requiring the use of the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

However I'm new to Phonegap so I have the following questions:

1. How does the Phonegap version relate to the Cordova version?
2. Is this affected by using Phonegap Build?
3. The cordova-plugin-whitelist does not seem to be available on the Phonegap Build website. Is there an alternative way to use a plugin if it is not available on the Phonegap Build website?

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: Which part of the code are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the access token in the config.xml:

From

```
<access origin="http://www.example.com*" />
```

...to...

```
<access origin="*"/>
```