# Phonegap Cordova file transfer with HTTPS protocol

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, https, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm working with `Phonegap 6.3.3`. I have to download a file. If my endpoint is a `HTTP` connection the operation is ok, but if endpoint use a `HTTPS` (TLS 1.2) connection `fileTransfer.download` return `error.code = 3`

```
    getDocumentFile : function(docId, fileName,successClb,errorClb){
        var url = this.endpoint + "/contents/getDocument?documentId=" + docId;
        var filePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + fileName;

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(
                    url,
                    filePath,
                    function(entry) {                           
                        successClb(entry.nativeURL);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                        errorClb(error);
                    },
                    false
                );
```

Usign ajax call with Jquery with `HTTPS` protocol I have not any problem.
Can you help me please?

Comment: On which platforms is this happening ? Did you install cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin ?

Comment: Android platform. I do not use whitelist plugin. How configure it?

Comment: You need to install the whitelist plugin and to config your config.xml file. Please check and the following stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757593/ajax-command-to-request-url-no-longer-working. Write if you have any issues

Comment: Sorry I used whitelist plugin my config.xml contains following directives: <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

Comment: the first directive should be <access origin="*" />, not <access origin="" />. The star (*) is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My first directive is:     <access origin="*" /> , it's not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128332/discussion-between-xristoeftimov-and-michel-foucault).

Comment: the error object of filetransfer.download is following:
{"code":3,"source":"https://192.168.250.155:8443/chp_backend/volantini/contents‌​/getDocument?documentId=2108","target":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/c‌​om.fly.app/files/file.pdf","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":"java.security.cert.Cer‌​tPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The correct call for HTTPS with certificate auto signed (not trusted) is following. It is important passing **true** to penultimate parameter (allowAllHost). For more information you read the [reference cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/)

```
new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(
                    url,
                    filePath,
                    success,
                    error,
                    true
                );
```